# ReactJS not compiles boostrap components. only returns HTML components. 0xerr011d

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I writes simple code for assignment. I refer documentations and couple of youtube video tutorial series. My react code is correct I'm not gets any errors while running the code. but these react-boostrap element not rendering . this codes only returns html output. please have a look at this code and help me to solve this problem.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';

import Test from './text';
ReactDOM.render(

    <Router>
        <div>
            <div>
                <App/>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Those are the index.html & index.js pages. I think those are enough for to discover problem. I will post competent as well as more information.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Logo from '../images/logo.png';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import AdminList from './AdminList';
import ClientList from './ClientList';
import ServiceList from './ServiceList';
import AdminView from './AdminView';
import ClientView from './ClientView';
import ServiceView from './ServiceView';
import AdminNew from './AdminNew';
import ClientNew from './ClientNew';
import ServiceNew from './ServiceNew';
import Category from './Category';
import CategoryNew from './CategoryNew';
import Login from './Login';
import App from '../App';


const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
    
      <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
      <Route path='/Category'
        render={({ match: { url } }) => (
          <div>
            <Route exact path={`${url}/`} component={Category} />
            <Route path={`${url}/new`} component={CategoryNew} />

          </div>
        )} />

      <Route path='/Client'
        render={({ match: { url } }) => (
          <div>
            <Route exact path={`${url}/`} component={ClientList} />
            <Route path={`${url}/new`} component={ClientNew} />
            <Route path={`${url}/view`} component={ClientView} />
          </div>
        )} />

      <Route path='/Service'

        render={({ match: { url } }) => (
          <div>
            <Route exact path={`${url}/`} component={ServiceList} />
            <Route path={`${url}/new`} component={ServiceNew} />
            <Route path={`${url}/view`} component={ServiceView} />
          </div>
        )} />

      <Route path='/Admin'

        render={({ match: { url } }) => (
          <div>
            <Route exact path={`${url}/`} component={AdminList} />
            <Route path={`${url}/new`} component={AdminNew} />
            <Route path={`${url}/view`} component={AdminView} />
          </div>
        )} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Main;
```

Main.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class ServiceNew extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            Name:'',
            NIC:'',
            Email:'',
            Password:'',
            Contact:'',
            District:'',
            Category:'',
        }
        this.handleNameChange=this.handleNameChange.bind(this)
        this.handleNICChange=this.handleNICChange.bind(this)
        this.handleEmailChange=this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)
        this.handlePwdChange=this.handlePwdChange.bind(this)
        this.handlePhoneChange=this.handlePhoneChange.bind(this)
        this.handleDistrictChange=this.handleDistrictChange.bind(this)
        this.handleCategoryChange=this.handleCategoryChange.bind(this)
        this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    handleNameChange(e){
        this.setState({
            Name:e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.Name)
    }
    handleNICChange(e){
        this.setState({
            NIC:e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.NIC)
    }
    handleEmailChange(e){
        this.setState({
            Email:e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.Email)
    }
    handlePwdChange(e){
        this.setState({
            Password:e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.Password)
    }
    handlePhoneChange(e){
        this.setState({
            Contact:e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.Contact)
    }
    handleDistrictChange(e){
        this.setState({
            District:e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.District)
    }
    handleCategoryChange(e){
        this.setState({
            Category:e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.Category)
    }
    handleClick = event =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/serviceproviders-insert',{
            name:this.state.Name,
            _id:this.state.NIC,
            email:this.state.Email,
            password:this.state.Password,
            contact:this.state.Contact,
            district:this.state.District,
            category:this.state.Category,
        })
        .then(res =>{
            alert("Successfully Registered");
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data)
            this.setState={
                Name:'',
                NIC:'',
                Email:'',
                Password:'',
                Contact:'',
                District:'',
                Category:'',
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
       
        
        
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <div>
                    <div class="well">

                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger"><h4><b>Add New</b></h4></a>

                    </div>


                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name:</label>
                            <input type="name" class="form-control" value={this.state.Name} id="name" placeholder="Enter name" name="name" onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nic">NIC:</label>
                            <input type="nic" class="form-control" value={this.state.NIC} id="nic" placeholder="Enter NIC" name="nic" onChange={this.handleNICChange}/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" value={this.state.Email} id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email"onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control"value={this.state.Password} id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" onChange={this.handlePwdChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Contact No:</label>
                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" value={this.state.Contact} id="phone" placeholder="Enter contact number" name="phone" onChange={this.handlePhoneChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="dis">District:</label>
                            <input type="dis" class="form-control" value={this.state.District} id="dis" placeholder="Enter district" name="dis" onChange={this.handleDistrictChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cat">Working Category:</label>
                            <input type="cat" class="form-control" value={this.state.Category} id="cat" placeholder="Enter working category" name="cat" onChange={this.handleCategoryChange}/>
                          </div>


                        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>





        );
    }
}
export default ServiceNew;
```

ServiceNew.js

This thing is write by my friend. he told me this codes completely runs on his computer without any problems.

Comment: `className` instead of `class`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `className` instead of `class` in React.

```
<div className="form-group">
   ...
</div>
```